# O que é savedInstanceState?

Tags: android

Sou novata no android e quero aprender mais então estou no github vendo uns projetos prontos e gostaria de saber o que é isso:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tempo_agora_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Esse savedInstanceState o que isso faz? Aliás me explica o que esse método faz?

Comment: Direto da fonte a explicação https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: Meu inglês é uma bosta...não tem português não moço?

Comment: Já foi dada a resposta, mas complemento dizendo que ela serve para quando voce gira a tela...Sabe? Nesse momento, a activity é destruída e reconstruída toda do zero. Então, na hora que alguém gira a tela, voce programa pra salvar os dados que estão naquela tela e depois os poe novamente na tela, agora em outra orientação (landscape ou portrait)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`savedInstanceState` é um parâmetro do método [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) que recebe um argumento do tipo [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html).

Ele é usado pelo sistema para, ao recriar uma Activity, permitir [restaurar o estado](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras) que ela tinha na altura em que foi destruída, por exemplo, devido ao usuário ter rodado o dispositivo.

Entenda-se que estado aqui apenas se refere ao conteúdo das views do layout da Activity, ou seja, o sistema apenas guarda automaticamente o estado do layout.
Qualquer outro tipo de informação que a Activity tenha será perdida, a não ser que seja explicitamente guardada nesse Bundle.

Para esse efeito a Activity disponibiliza o método [onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) que é chamado antes da Activity poder vir a ser destruída. O sistema passa a ele o objecto Bundle que mais tarde é recuperado no método `onCreate()` quando a Activity for recriada, permitindo que seja guardada e depois recuperada outro tipo de informação.

Exemplo da [documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState) onde se guarda o valor das variáveis `mCurrentScore` e `mCurrentLevel`:

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";
...

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

que depois são recuperadas no `onCreate()`, se a Activity tiver sido recriada:

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
    }
    ...
}
```

No exemplo de código que colocou na pergunta o `savedInstanceState` apenas está a ser utilizado para verificar se o `onCreate()` está a ser chamado devido a uma recriação da Activity ou não.

Se `savedInstanceState == null` é porque a Activity está a ser criada pela primeira vez, nesse caso é criado o *PlaceholderFragment* e colocado no `R.id.container`.