# Como posso "manter" os dados de uma Activity quando rotaciona a tela?

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma Activity que faz uma requisição HTTP usando AsyncTask, o resultado dessa requisição é enviado para um método que atualiza minha UI. Porém quando eu rotaciono a tela, os dados preenchidos nas TextViews são removidos.

Como posso "manter" esses dados ao rotacionar a tela?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é savedInstanceState?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168372/2541)

Comment: Muito obrigado, @ramaral...exatamente o que eu queria. Problema resolvido.

Answer (score -1):

**Para activity's**

**Para salvar os dados**

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Salve todos seus dados aqui, lembrando que se for objeto é preciso ser serializable ou de preferencia parcelable
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

    // Sempre chamar a super classe depois de salvar as instancias
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

**Para recuperar os dados**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //Sempre chamar a super classe primeiro

    // Verifique se existe algo para restaurar
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restaurando os valores padrão
        mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
    } else {
        // Não existe valores para restaurar
    }
    ...
}
```

**[Mais detalhes nesse link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html?hl=pt-br)**

**Recomendo não usar AsyncTask e sim [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) para HTTP** e para threads recomendo usar [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) e [RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle) para controlar o ciclo de vida

Comment: Obrigado @Duanniston, eu utilizei exatamente esses métodos e funcionou.
Quanto as recomendações, agradeço e vou estuda-las. 
Já tinham me recomendado o **Retrofit**, apenas usei o AsyncTask para conhecimento e estudo.