# Dúvida sobre sintaxe do Android Activity e o método "onCreate" e o que são seus argumentos!

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Sou novato no mundo da programação e tenho estudado java. Estou querendo entender a aplicação de Java para apps Android e me deparei com estes métodos da `Activity`.

A teoria eu compreendo sem problemas, porém eu empaco na sintaxe. Basicamente eu preciso que alguém explique o que esses termos significam e porque eles estão dispostos da forma que estão. Por exemplo:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Eu sei que `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){` é um método; sei que `Bundle` e `savedInstanceState` são parâmetros/argumentos deste método, sei o que eles alegadamente fazem que é salvar estados de informação para permitir serem recuperados após alguma interrupção na `Activity`, porém minhas dúvidas são:

- O que exatamente é um `Bundle`? Certamente é um parâmetro para o método, mas, varias coisas podem ser parâmetros. É uma variável? Objeto? Classe? Outro método (é possível?)
- O que é e da onde vem `Bundle` e `savedInstanceState`?
- E quanto a sintaxe dentro do escopo das outras linhas (`onCreate` e `setContentview`)?

Estou confuso porque não sei da onde vem esses elementos, sei que vem de alguma biblioteca importada, mas o que eles são ou representam?

Comment: "*`Bundle` e `savedInstanceState` são parâmetros*" - não, só tem **um** parâmetro aí, que é o `savedInstanceState`. `Bundle` é o tipo dele (no caso, [a classe chamada `Bundle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle)).

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é savedInstanceState?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168372/100416)

Comment: Estude Java primeiro. Depois vá para Android. Na verdade eu nem sei se recomendo uma abordagem "objects first" para aprender programação. Talvez fosse melhor estudar um paradigma mais simples primeiro, um procedural, talvez um funcional, um Python, um JavaScript, mas focando no procedural e na lógica de programação. É duro, a gente quer ensinar a estudar certo, e não para que vire "só mais um programador meia-boca" como tem muitos por aí (me incluo nessa).

Comment: Bom... eu não acho Orientação a Objetos coisa de outro mundo, tenho noções de programação procedural, não sou tão leigo assim e tenho aprendido muita coisa de forma relativamente rápida e até mais rápida que imaginava que aprenderia... algumas implementações de sintaxe me deixam em duvida como se é possível colocar classes como parâmetros de métodos e o que são certos parâmetros em relação a essas classes, coisas que se forem respondidas resolverão 70% de certos problemas de compreensão que tenho atualmente.

Comment: Orientação a objetos a teoria parece simples, mas ela bem feita é complicada de aprender, leva tempo. E mal feita parece bonitinha no começo mas só aumenta complexidade no médio e longo prazos, engessa o código, provoca má abstração e acomplamento excessivo, porque as más decisões de design vão se acumulando. Por isso a recomendação de pegar bem o procedural primeiro. Se está estudando Java, não deveria ter essas dúvidas de classe e objeto no Android, somente dúvidas específicas do Android.

Comment: Se você tem essas dúvidas, sugiro aprender a usar o Stack Overflow em português. Pesquise por exemplo [diferença+classe+objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=diferen%C3%A7a+classe+objeto)

Comment: Entendi... mas diz ai... se Bundle é uma classe e é possível colocá-la como parâmetro pra outro método isso significa que é possível importar os atributos, variáveis e até métodos internos dessa classe dentro do escopo do método que recebe ela como parâmetro? e quanto ao savedInstanceState, ele é o que dentro do Bundle?

Comment: `savedInstanceState` **é** um `Bundle` (para ser mais preciso, ele é uma instância da classe `Bundle`). Como o @Piovezan já disse - e desculpe se parecer rude, mas é pra te ajudar - primeiro vc deve estudar Java, pois parece que está com dificuldade em entender os fundamentos básicos da linguagem (por exemplo, diferença entre classe e instância da classe, o que são parâmetros de um método, etc). Depois de entender como a linguagem funciona, aí vc parte pro Android, pra entender como/quando/porque cada método é chamado em cada situação, etc

Comment: Eu ia tentar explicar certinho mas me enrolei, o @hkotsubo passou na minha frente. Diferença entre [parâmetro e argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/357). É como ele falou. Procure um bom material sobre Java, numa lembrança rápida posso sugerir por exemplo o da Caelum, que costuma ser bem falado, mas não cheguei a olhar o material a fundo: https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos.pdf se você souber inglês eu prefiro os tutoriais da Oracle (_The Java Tutorials_). Vídeos eu não sei.

Comment: Sim, são duvidas básicas não nego. quando me deparei com a programação do android percebi o choque de diferença de estruturação em relação ao pc, mesmo sendo java e também orientação a objetos. Também já havia pensando em voltar a focar no java e deixar o android como secundário, mas fiquei na duvida se estava apenas sendo covarde ou inventando desculpa na minha mente para simplesmente não estudar.

Comment: Programar é muito divertido. Não quero me prolongar. A internet tem muito material mas muita coisa não se salva, e o melhor está em inglês, tem que filtrar o que vai estudar para aprender corretamente e não ter que "desaprender" o errado depois. Você tem um cérebro novo, saboros... digo, espaçoso kkkk, tem que aproveitar que é jovem para firmar conceitos corretos, formar a base. Procure estudar, fazer um bom curso na área, se possível, se for isso que quer fazer.

Comment: Enfim. Sugiro que pesquise algo como "Como aprender a programar do jeito certo" e leia algumas das respostas que encontrar.

Answer (score 2):

`Bundle` é uma classe cuja função é salvar e recuperar informações de estado sobre a `Activity` em questão. Há certas situações, como mudança de orientação do aparelho (retrato p/ paisagem, por exemplo), em que a `Activity` precisa ser reconstruída e o estado anterior dela recuperado, nesse caso, o `onCreate` é chamado e, no `Bundle`, estarão as informações da `Activity` para que ela possa ser recriada da maneira como estava antes do evento que chamou esse `onCreate`.

O `setContentView` basicamente "desenha" a `Activity`. Ele recebe como parâmetro uma referência a um arquivo XML que representa o "desenho", a esquematização gráfica do que vai ser exibido para o usuário. Em outras palavras, cada "tela" de um app é uma `Activity`, construída a partir de um arquivo XML.

Comment: Isso. Falou muito bem.